# React-native setup of Moengage errors when running android: package MoEngage does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, moengage

I'm installing MoEngage sdk and `react-native-moengage` packages on my react native app, but I have been unable so far to run the app even after following the guide in the [official site](https://docs.moengage.com/docs/sdk-integration-2)

Removing everything related to moengage makes the app run again, so I don't believe it's a different package or bad config

I tried cleaning gradle, running from CLI, running from android studio, running in a physical device, changing the versions of appcompat (breaking other things, so I'd rather not do that again)... Up to no avail.

Currently running:

- Windows 10 64bits
- React native 0.59.8. It's not a new app, it started in 0.55.4 and migrated to 0.59.8 over time.
- Gradle build tools 3.3.0 and gradle version 4.10.1-all

```
// app/build.gradle

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-moengage')
    implementation 'com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:+'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])    
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    ...
}
```

```
// settings.gradle

include ':react-native-moengage'
project(':react-native-moengage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-moengage/android')
```

```java
//MainApplication.java

...
import com.moengage.react.MoEReactPackage;
...


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
...

  @Override
  public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }

  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new MoEReactPackage(),
    );
  }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MoEngage moEngage =
        new MoEngage.Builder(this, "XXX")
            .build();
    MoEngage.initialise(moEngage);
  }
```

So far I've only gotten the following message

```sh
...project\android\app\src\main\java\io\lifevision\MainApplication.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
    MoEngage moEngage =
    ^
  symbol:   class MoEngage
  location: class MainApplication
...project\android\app\src\main\java\io\lifevision\MainApplication.java:96: error: package MoEngage does not exist
        new MoEngage.Builder(this, "UZXYFJ0V2RQRUFJTMVHOAJKC")
                    ^
...project\android\app\src\main\java\io\lifevision\MainApplication.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
    MoEngage.initialise(moEngage);
    ^
  symbol:   variable MoEngage
  location: class MainApplication
3 errors
```

Comment: If it's the additional `,` at the end of the array, it's because I removed the packages under it to not clutter the answer, it's not the last package

Comment: You should change your key :  "UZXYFJ0V2RQRUFJTMVHOAJKC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import statement for MoEngage.java is missing. Below is the required import statement

```
import com.moengage.core.MoEngage;
```

I would recommend you to enable auto-import in your IDE(Android Studio) it will help you manage the imports.

Let me if this does not solve your issue. Alternatively you can write to us at support@moengage.com

Comment: I was working with VScode so I did not have auto imports. Missed out on it due to copy pasting everything instead of typing it myself but this worked, thanks!